# Use jQuery 2.x on Meteor APP

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I would like update my current jQuery version on my Meteor projet 1.x to 2.x. Do you know how i can update this module ?

I also have an error 'module jQuery not found'. I would like update my jQuery version for use Foundation framework :

```
Error: Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
```

Thank you ! :)

**EDIT**

Fix : Install jQuery with

> meteor npm install --save jquery meteor-node-stubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install JQuery with `meteor npm install --save jquery meteor-node-stubs`